# Vue single file components don't load properly using webpack

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I am trying to load vue single files components using webpack but it's not working, Instead of the component, it show this:

```
<!--function(e,t,n,r){return rn(i,e,t,n,r, !0)}-->
```

This is my index.html:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="app">        
    <question></question>
    {{ parent }}
</div>
<script src="dist/app.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

webpack.config.js :

```
const path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: ['./assets/app.js'],

  output: {
    filename: 'app.min.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }, 

  module: {
    rules: [

      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader'
      }


    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    // make sure to include the plugin!
    new VueLoaderPlugin()
  ],

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      vue: 'vue/dist/vue.min.js'
      }
  }

};
```

package.js:

```
{
  "name": "moderncss"      
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-loader": "^15.4.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17",
    "webpack": "^3.12.0"
  }
}
```

app.js:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
Vue.component("question", require("./components/Question.vue"));

new Vue({
 el:"#app",
 data:{
    parent:'parent data'
 }  
});
```

Question.vue:

```
<template>    
    <div>
        Question component 
    </div>      
</template>
```

I tried to add some parent data {{ parent }} and it is displaying ok, but the component is the problem, what is happening? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```js
//app.js
window.Vue = require('vue');
Vue.component("question", require("./components/Question.vue").default);

new Vue({
 el:"#app",
 data:{
    parent:'parent data'
 }  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The default webpack version of vue only includes the vue runtime, not the template compiler.

Therefor the contents of the `<div id="app">` won't be compiled into render function.

If you can't compile all templates at compile time, use the compiled-included build by editing your webpack.config.js:

```
alias: {
  'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
}
```

But in this case I recommend moving the template into a App.vue file.

```
// in app.js
import App from "./App.vue"
const app = new Vue(App)
app.$mount('#app')
```

.

```
// in App.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <question></question>
    {{ parent }}
  </div>
</template>
```